# Программа мгновенного обмена сообщениями на C#

Tags: c#, xmpp, icq

Собственно задался вопросом написания программы для быстрого обмена сообщениями с использованием протоколов ICQ, XMPP на C#. Есть ли заготовки, или готовый IM на C# с открытым исходным кодом и какие технологии необходимо знать для написания такого?

Comment: Главный вопрос, которым вы должны задаться, это "зачем"? А о деталях можно подумать потом

Comment: Затем, что бы получить опыта в разработке, да и просто для себя.

Comment: Для того, чтобы опыт получить, надо всё делать самому и с нуля.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [agsXMPP SDK](http://www.ag-software.de/agsxmpp-sdk/)
- [Jabber Client](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/JabberClient.aspx) на agsXMPP SDK
- [jabber-net](http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/)

Comment: Вот ( http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/source/checkout ) нашел нашел jabber клиент на .net с открытым исходным кодам благодаря вашим ссылкам. Спасибо!